# Not able to connect to tftp server locally (<ip>: bad port number)

Tags: tftp

On my host OS, I have set up a TFTP server on port 69 using tftpd64. When I try to connect from my VM to the TFTP server using the command: `atftp --get <file_name> <host_os_ip>`, I get the following error message:
"[ip]: bad port number.
Not connected."

I have verified that port 69 is listening on the host OS using the command
`netstat -ano | find ":69 "` and confirmed that the PID corresponds with the PID of tftpd64.

My VM is on the same subnet as my host OS, and I have verified they can communicate using ping.

I have also checked the Windows firewall to make sure port 69 is not being blocked.

Comment: `tftp` uses an ephemeral port for transferring data. Does the firewall allow connections on ports greater than 1024?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I temporarily added a firewall rule that allows connections from all ports on the local network, and it still gave me the same error message. If I set up a nc listener on my host OS on a port greater than 1024, I am able to connect from my VM, so I don't believe this is the problem. @doneal24